# probability that chi-squared random variable is less than other chi-squared random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, chi-squared

I have random variables $X_i = \mathcal N(0,\sigma_1^2)$ and $Y_i = \mathcal N(0,\sigma_2^2) $ where i = 0, 1 ,..., n. all of them are independent to one another

I obtained random variable $X = X_1^2 + X_2^2 + ... X_n^2$ and $Y=Y_1^2+Y_2^2...Y_n^2$ are chi-squared random variables with n degrees of freedom

I want to find the probability $P(X<Y)$, I can find the $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$

but i can not calculate 
$P(X<Y) = \int_{0}^{\infty}P(X<y)f_Y(y)dy$
because $P(X<y)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are complicated

Is there other method to find $P(X<Y)$ without above integral method? 
I really want to calculated the probability $P(X<Y)$

Comment: HINT: $P(X>Y) = P(Y>X)$ by symmetry.

Comment: Note that you obtain a chi-square random variable when you are summing the squares of i.i.d. standard normal random variables. So in general you are actually having a scaled chi-square (gamma) distribution. Consider $\displaystyle \Pr\{X < Y\} = \Pr\left\{\frac {(X / \sigma_1) / n} {(Y / \sigma_2) / n } < \frac {\sigma_2} {\sigma_1} \right\}$ The LHS is the ratio of two independent chi-squared random variables with d.f. $n$ each, so the probability is the CDF of a $F(n, n)$ distribution evaluated at $\displaystyle  \frac {\sigma_2} {\sigma_1}$.